# can not read property of undefined url

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

i want do something like this

in my blog app user can not post without uploading image untill handle the request  . post need 1 image to be published
i want do something that user can post without uploading image i mean image image not necessary

i do like this

```
           const { url?...url, public_id: publicId } = await uploadToCloudinary(file, 
          'Posts');
```

but it gieves error that url is is not defined

here is my post controller

```
const Post = require('../model/Post');
const User = require('../model/User');
const Tag = require('../model/Tag');
const Comment = require('../model/Comment');
const cloudinary = require('../config/cloudinary');
const { uploadToCloudinary } = require('../utils/cloudinary');
const { getPostParams, unCapitalizeFirstLetter } = require('../helpers/string');
const { createTags, updateTags, deleteTags } = require('./tagsController');
const {
    likeNotification,
    removeLikeNotification,
    postNotification,
    removePostNotification,
} = require('./notificationsController');

const createPost = async (req, res) => {
    const { title,file, tags,body, authorUsername } = req.body;

    const { url, public_id: publicId } = await uploadToCloudinary(file, 'Posts');
    const author = await User.findOne({ username: authorUsername }).exec();

    const formattedTags = tags
        .trim()
        .split(',')
        .map(w => w.trim().replace(/ /g, '-'));

    const createdPost = await Post.create({
        title,
        image:{ url, publicId },
        body,
        author: author._id,
    });

    author.followers.map(followerId => {
        (async () => {
            await postNotification(author._id, createdPost._id, followerId);
        })();
    });

    await createTags(formattedTags, createdPost);

    author.posts.push(createdPost._id);

    await author.save();

    res.status(200).json(createdPost.toObject({ getters: true }));
};

const getPost = async (req, res) => {
    const author = await User.findOne({ username: req.params.username }).exec();
    const authorId = await author?.toObject({ getters: true }).id;
    const { postTitle, postId } = getPostParams(req.params.postUrl);

    const foundPost = await Post.findOne({
        author: authorId,
        title: postTitle,
        _id: postId,
    })
        .populate('author')
        .populate('comments')
        .populate('tags')
        .exec();

    res.status(200).json(foundPost.toObject({ getters: true }));
};

const getPosts = async (req, res) => {
    const { userId } = req.params;

    const posts = await Post.find(userId ? { bookmarks: userId } : {})
        .sort({ createdAt: -1 })
        .populate('author')
        .populate('tags');
    if (!posts) res.status(204).json('No posts found');

    res.status(200).json(posts.map(post => post.toObject({ getters: true })));
};

const updatePost = async (req, res) => {
    const authorId = await User.findOne({ username: req.params.username }).exec();
    const { postTitle, postId } = getPostParams(req.params.postUrl);

    const { url, public_id: publicId } = await uploadToCloudinary(req.body.image.url, 'Posts');

    await cloudinary.uploader.destroy(req.body.image.publicId);

    req.body.image = { url, publicId };
    const formattedTags = req.body.tags
        .trim()
        .split(',')
        .map(w => w.trim().replace(/ /g, '-'));

    const post = await Post.findOne({
        author: authorId,
        title: postTitle,
        _id: postId,
    })
        .populate('author')
        .populate('tags');

    Object.keys(req.body).map(key => {
        if (key !== 'tags') post[key] = req.body[key];
    });

    await updateTags(formattedTags, post);

    await post.save();

    res.status(200).json(post.toObject({ getters: true }));
};

const deletePostsByUserId = async user => {
    const { _id: userId } = user;

    user.comments.forEach(commentId => {
        (async () => {
            await Post.updateMany({ comments: commentId }, { $pull: { comments: commentId } });
        })();
    });

    const posts = await Post.find({ author: userId }).populate('tags');

    ['likes', 'unicorns', 'bookmarks'].forEach(k => {
        (async () => {
            await Post.updateMany({ [k]: userId }, { $pull: { [k]: userId } });
        })();
    });

    posts.forEach(post => {
        (async () => {
            await deleteTags(
                post.tags.map(({ name }) => name),
                post,
                true
            );
            await cloudinary.uploader.destroy(post.image.publicId);
            await Post.deleteOne({ _id: post._id });
        })();
    });

    await Comment.deleteMany({ author: userId });
};

const deletePost = async (req, res) => {
    const author = await User.findOne({ username: req.params.username }).exec();
    const { postTitle, postId } = getPostParams(req.params.postUrl);

    await cloudinary.uploader.destroy(req.body.publicId);

    const foundPost = await Post.findOne({
        author: author._id,
        title: postTitle,
        _id: postId,
    })
        .populate('tags')
        .exec();

    if (!foundPost) return res.sendStatus(204);

    const comments = await Comment.find({ parentPost: postId }).populate({
        path: 'author',
        populate: 'followers',
    });

    comments.forEach(({ author }) =>
        (async () => {
            author.comments.forEach(comment => author.comments.pull(comment));
        })()
    );
    author.posts.pull(postId);
    await author.save();

    await Comment.deleteMany({ parentPost: postId });

    await deleteTags(
        foundPost.tags.map(({ name }) => name),
        foundPost,
        true
    );

    removePostNotification(author._id, foundPost._id, author.followers);

    await Post.deleteOne({ _id: foundPost._id });

    res.status(200).json(foundPost.toObject({ getters: true }));
};

const postReaction = async (req, res) => {
    const { userId } = req.body;
    const { action, postUrl } = req.params;
    const { postTitle, postId } = getPostParams(postUrl);
    const isUndoing = action.includes('remove');
    const actionKey = isUndoing
        ? unCapitalizeFirstLetter(action.replace('remove', '')) + 's'
        : action + 's';

    const author = await User.findOne({ username: req.params.username }).exec();
    const authorId = await author.toObject({ getters: true }).id;

    const updatedPost = await Post.findOneAndUpdate(
        { author: authorId, title: postTitle, _id: postId },
        isUndoing ? { $pull: { [actionKey]: userId } } : { $addToSet: { [actionKey]: userId } },
        { new: true, timestamps: false }
    );

    if (isUndoing) await removeLikeNotification(userId, updatedPost._id, authorId);
    else await likeNotification(userId, updatedPost._id, authorId);

    res.status(200).json(updatedPost.toObject({ getters: true }));
};

module.exports = {
    createPost,
    getPosts,
    getPost,
    updatePost,
    deletePost,
    deletePostsByUserId,
    postReaction,
};
```

and here is my post Model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const PostSchema = new Schema(
  {
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    image: { url: { type: String }, publicId: { type: String } },
    body: { type: String, required: true },
    likes: [{ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
    unicorns: [{ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
    bookmarks: [{ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
    tags: [{ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'Tag' }],
    comments: [{ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'Comment' }],
    author: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'User' },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
```

I change

```
  
    const { url, public_id: publicId } = await uploadToCloudinary(req.body.image.url, 'Posts');
```

to

```
const { url?...url, public_id: publicId } = await uploadToCloudinary(req.body.image.url, 'Posts');
```

this is utils/cloudinary.js

```
const cloudinary = require('../config/cloudinary');

const uploadToCloudinary = async (file, folder) => {
  try {
    const uploadedResponse = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(file, {
      folder: `evToClone/${folder}`,
    });
    return uploadedResponse;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};

module.exports = { uploadToCloudinary };
```

but it gives errors url is not defined
sorry for bad english
what can i do to make this possible ?
user can post without uploading to cloudinary

Comment: url?...url is not right syntax. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Ralle  the user after sign up wants create post in my blog . but uploading image is required . i want make it not require. i did change the post model to not require and in front end not require . but here in post controller.js the app wants upload image to cloudinary . but i do not want . i want say if url exist then u upload . this url i think it means the file or the input image . i mean if they pick image in input image and then they submit form . if they did not picked any image to upload . u not upload . sorry for bad english

Comment: Can you post also ../utils/cloudinary.

Comment: @Ralle i am really happy u answering me . thank you brother . i did add cloudinary to my question thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do like so:

Looking to your code, the image is in the body, so i guess you are sending that base64 encoded. (Cant be sure as i dont see that part of your code).

If in your frontend you decide to not send an image, just send, file: null.

Then in the backend you will have it also null.

```
    const { title,file, tags,body, authorUsername } = req.body;
```

So now wrap the part of image upload.

```
  let urlData = {}
  if(file) {
  urlData= await uploadToCloudinary(file, 'Posts');
  }
  const { url, public_id: publicId } = urlData || {url:null,public_id: null} // asigns default
```

In this way if a file is there it will be send. Then or the data are assigned by desstructuring to url and publicId or it will take the null values. (|| {url:null,public_id: null}).

Do the same for the update part.

Hint. When this work you can play arround and implement a better errorhandling.

What if the user sends an image but for some reason the upload fails?

Comment: this soloution u gave me it workded for add post  .   why this solution not work when user try to edit post . i mean for editing post user have to add image again . if u see my post controller file . u can finde this line this is for updating post but not same as add post                     const updatePost = async (req, res) => {
    const authorId = await User.findOne({ username: req.params.username }).exec();
    const { postTitle, postId } = getPostParams(req.params.postUrl);

    const { url, public_id: publicId } = await uploadToCloudinary(req.body.image.url, 'Posts');

Comment: I mean the answer u gave me it worked . and user thanks to you . now can add post without adding image .  but in my postcontroller.js file . there is a code for updating post .  I add the code u gave me for updating post . but not work like adding post . i mean why this solution work for adding post . and not working for updating post . what can i do sir .

Comment: for updating post . i get errors like this           UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason

Comment: wrap all in a try catch and analyse the error. You have several code snpilets without any errorhandling. If you are using axios somewhere, think axios returns error in the response, without throwing an error itselfs. In that case you need to analyse the response.

Comment: i did this process again with more attention . it gives this error        if(file) {
[0]             ^
[0]
[0] ReferenceError: file is not defined              why is file defined for add post ? their both in postcontroller.js    what do you think ? i do something wrong ?

Comment: Do you have a demosite or github repo. So i can check it?

Comment: yes i did this before .    but for post controller . i did not add my newpostcontroller file .   https://github.com/am0029/latest-dev-to-clone

Comment: the post controller file the only change is for postcontroller u should add your answer to it  . i did it in local host and it worked for adding post but for updating post i have problems

Comment: u can see in my github . if u want the new postcontroller file, i edit in my question